# php-fpm can't start up "unknown entry '$listen'"

Tags: php, centos7, fpm

I install php7 on centos7,but I use 'systemctl start php-fpm' command,

it can't startup,so I execute "systemctl status php-fpm.service",and get the result below:

```
# systemctl status php-fpm.service
● php-fpm.service - The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/php-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-03-03 15:31:52 EST; 7min ago
  Process: 12841 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize (code=exited, status=78)
 Main PID: 12841 (code=exited, status=78)

Mar 03 15:31:51 instance-1 systemd[1]: Starting The PHP FastCGI Process Manager...
Mar 03 15:31:52 instance-1 php-fpm[12841]: [03-Mar-2018 15:31:52] ERROR: [/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:12] unknown entry '#listen'
Mar 03 15:31:52 instance-1 php-fpm[12841]: [03-Mar-2018 15:31:52] ERROR: Unable to include /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf from /etc/php-fpm.conf at line 12
Mar 03 15:31:52 instance-1 php-fpm[12841]: [03-Mar-2018 15:31:52] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php-fpm.conf'
Mar 03 15:31:52 instance-1 php-fpm[12841]: [03-Mar-2018 15:31:52] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
Mar 03 15:31:52 instance-1 systemd[1]: php-fpm.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=78/n/a
Mar 03 15:31:52 instance-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP FastCGI Process Manager.
Mar 03 15:31:52 instance-1 systemd[1]: Unit php-fpm.service entered failed state.
Mar 03 15:31:52 instance-1 systemd[1]: php-fpm.service failed.
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: so, you could read it, or post it here : `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`, to get help figuring out what the `#listen` is on line 12

Comment: In fpm config files the comment character is `;` and not `#`